Unable to detach kitchen faucet
I'm attempting to replace a kitchen faucet but unable to unscrew nuts holding the large stabilizing piece in place. I have them mostly unscrewed, but they are down against a plastic piece attaching a water line to the faucet. It seems like I need to detach the water line, but I can't tell.
From top to bottom: there's the large stabilizing piece, followed by two thin nuts, then the black & white plastic thing, which attaches to the brass piece, which then attaches to the water line.
Any advice greatly appreciated; I'm stuck! If more information would be helpful please let me know and I'll add what I can.

unplug the black/white connector, then unscrew the nut

Was able to get the line unscrewed, so the connector is more accessible now. Doesn't seem to unscrew and not having any luck prying it off yet. Edit: found this, so that's next: https://solutions.moen.com/Article_Library/Removing_Quick_Connects

Detaching the water line is normal and expected. The faucet didn't go in with them attached, and it won't come out with them attached. Looks like the white piece pulls out of the black one at 90 degrees to the pipe, probably releasing the black piece (i.e. it looks like a locking or latching insert, differently colored to make it obvious.) If you have it further apart, [edit] in an updated picture of where you've gotten to. Alternately, the picture suggests that the part the nuts tighten above has a gap on the backside to slip over the pipe when loose.

Issue was that I didn't understand how Moen's "quick connects" worked. I was able to use a combination of fingers, pliers, and a small screwdriver to get the white piece of the quick connect backed out. Once backed out most of the way, the quick connect was loose enough to pull off with some effort.
This was the breakthrough guide: https://solutions.moen.com/Article_Library/Removing_Quick_Connects
